# Lubuntu18.04.1LTS can't highlited a select menu of gedit 3.28.1

Tags: lubuntu

title : Lubuntu18.04.1LTS can't highlited a select menu of gedit 3.28.1

What happened is the following phenomenon.

2018.09.02

In Gedit 3.18.3 (Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS Desktop 64bit)
When I select a menu item with the mouse pointer,
The selected item will turn blue.(Highlighted)

However, in Gedit 3.28.1 (Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop 64bit)
When I select a menu item with the mouse pointer,
The selected item will not turn blue.

I can not select items with the arrow keys. Because
When selecting with arrow key
The color of the selected item is not changed.

In the similar phenomenon,
When Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS's Firefox Quantum displays the bookmark menu
I select a bookmark by mouse pointer then It was not highlighted.

I can not select a bookmark with the arrow keys. Because
When selecting with arrow key
The color of the selected bookmark is not changed.

However,
Selected bookmarks were highlighted by Firefox Quantum on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Which widget (gtk) theme are you using?

Comment: Thank you DK Bose. Nice suggestion! I use "Rareigh"widjet. but return to "lubuntu default"widjet then problem was solved!